# sharepoint vs wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sharepoint

I need to develop a small Real Estate Agent website for my friend where i can put across my content across tabs like
New poperty, Any Queries,Contact Us, About Us etc. AFAIK , i have two options to quickly develop it i.e wordpress or sharepoint.
i have gone thru some stuff over net to help me to decide among two. Now i am inclined towards wordpress. Reasons are:-

> 1)Share Point is good for application which are rich in business logic
>   like  one with with named users, permissions,  groups, file
>   structures, and document sharing.Good for applications which needs to
>   scalable.
>
> Probably we can do every stuff on wordpress also, but we need to
>   depend on third party libraries apart from word press. But sharepoint
>   probably provides many utilities/features in single bundle.
>
> 2)I am java guy and laymen to dot net, so it would better to work on
>   wordpress(PHP based) than on sharePoint.

My assumption is that share point comes under freeware(share point fondation) and paid version also. But not what extra paid version
provides over freeware? I referred to link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-vs-sharepoint to come at my understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of main differences about the sharepoint foundation and the paid version, is that the foundation don't include the publishing features on this link http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/06/23/sharepoint-publishing-features-functionality.aspx you can read more about them and then decide if they will be useful for you or not.

If you will create a site where you need to manage a lot of data and store tables and things like that I definitely recommend you the SharePoint.

If you will create a site just to show some information the wordpress is what you should choose.

Do you have considered Office 365, it includes all the features of the paid SharePoint server version, and also includes the public facing websites that are very easy and cheap to brand with tools like www.bindtuning.com

Comment: but office 365 is also paid. Right?what do u mean by "office 365 also includes the public facing websites that are very easy and cheap to brand with tools like www.bindtuning.com"

Comment: Yes, the Office 365 is paid you can see the pricing plans here http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans-FX102918419.aspx The public facing websites are public SharePoint sites that you can use to make your site here is an example http://www.repointdk.com/

Comment: Sharepoint Foundation is free (license is included in Windows Server license) but only for intranet scopes.
In you want to publish a Sharepoint site over the internet, you have to buy the Internet Connector.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Sharepoint developer but i think using WordPress for this application can be the better solution.
There are lot of third party templates for Real Estates application based on WordPress. 
With few dollars you can get a good starting point and thanks to your php knowledge you can customize it if necessary.

If you want to obtain the same result with Sharepoint, i think you have to write a lot of code.